# Notation clarification on covariate for CUPED in Microsoft 2013 Paper

Tags: variance, notation

I just wrote a [post about CUPED](https://medium.com/before-data-science/how-to-double-a-b-testing-speed-with-cuped-f80460825a90) so I can learn about the method. The source for the post is [Deng 2013](https://exp-platform.com/Documents/2013-02-CUPED-ImprovingSensitivityOfControlledExperiments.pdf?source=responses-----f80460825a90----0-----------------respond_sidebar-----------), but it's unclear to me how the initial formula for CUPED keeps the covariate term (equation 3, section 3.2.1).

If CUPED is defined to be `Yhat = Ybar − θXbar + θEX` and `−θE(Xbar) + θE(X) = 0`, then how is there a CUPED adjustment term left? And that includes for the variance calculation.

Note that for the blog post I the formula in a [Netflix paper](https://www.kdd.org/kdd2016/papers/files/adp0945-xieA.pdf).

Comment: Maybe you could include a short description of CUPED, what it is, at least explain the acronym?

Comment: Hey Kjetil - thanks for the comment. The post linked above outlines the method in the intro paragraph. CUPED stands for Controlling experiment Using Pre-Existing Data. It uses data prior to the experiment to remove variance that is "natural" in our north star metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Preamble

As explained in the comment, CUPED stands for Controlled Experiment Using Pre-Experiment Data. It is used to increase the power of A/B tests, and is very popular with the tech companies like Microsoft, Netflix, Facebook etc.

Loosely speaking, the idea is that you use some suitable data (usually pre-experiment) to explain away some of the variance in the data from your experiment. The result is that you can detect smaller effects or conclude your experiment sooner. At big tech companies even small effect sizes or putting a change into production even a week sooner can correspond to large amounts of money.

### The question

I will walk through that section of the linked [article](https://Controlled%20Experiment%20Using%20Pre-Experiment%20Data) (article title in case the link dies, Improving the Sensitivity of Online Controlled Experiments
by Utilizing Pre-Experiment Data, Deng, Xu, Kohavi, Walker).

We start at equation $(3)$.
$$\hat{Y} = \bar{Y} - \theta \bar{X} + \theta E[X] \hspace{1cm}(3)$$

In the article they note the following, which I will label $(\star)$

$$-\theta E[\bar{X}] + \theta E[X]=0 \hspace{1cm} (\star)$$

First, let's check we understand all the pieces here. The sample mean $\bar{X}$ is an estimate for the true, population mean $\mu$. The sample mean is an unbiased estimator, so $E[\bar{X}]=\mu$.  Also, we have that $E[X]=\mu$ by definition. This explains the observation $(\star)$.

Now in equation $(3)$ I think you may have misread it. Notice that we have $-\theta \bar{X}$ and *not* $-\theta E[\bar{X}]$, and so the last two terms in $(3)$ do not cancel. I think this is the issue confusing the OP.

However I will run through the first part of section 3.2.1 of the paper just to explain the details.

In the paper, they then claim $\hat{Y}$ is an unbiased estimator of $E[Y]$. This means that $E[\hat{Y}]=E[Y]$

We can see this,
$$E[\hat{Y}]=E[\bar{Y} - \theta \bar{X} + \theta E[X]] = E[\bar{Y}]-\theta E[\bar{X}]+\theta E[E[X]]$$
by the linearity property of expectation. Then also note the fact that $E[E[X]]=E[X]$ and so we have
$$ E[\bar{Y}]-\theta E[\bar{X}]+\theta[E[X]]$$
finally use our observation $(\star)$, this becomes
$$E[\bar{Y}]$$
and so we have
$$E[\hat{Y}] = E[\bar{Y}] = E[Y]$$

### Why care?

The reason this matters is we are showing we can use $\hat{Y}$ instead of $\bar{Y}$, for our experiment. Why would we do that? Well the next steps in the paper show that
$var(\hat{Y}) = var(\bar{Y})(1-\rho^2)$

So $var(\hat{Y})$ is no bigger than $var(\bar{Y})$. If $X$ is chosen well then we get a large value of $\rho$ and we can significantly reduce our variance.